# Execute Subquery refactoring first before any other SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, subquery, query-optimization

I Have a very complex view which is of the below form

```
create or replace view loan_vw as 
select * from (with loan_info as (select loan_table.*,commission_table.* 
                                   from loan_table,
                                  commission_table where 
                                  contract_id=commission_id)
                select /*complex transformations */ from loan_info
                where type <> 'PRINCIPAL'
                union all 
                select /*complex transformations */ from loan_info
                where type = 'PRINCIPAL')
```

Now IF I do the below select the query hangs

```
         select * from loan_vw where contract_id='HA001234TY56';
```

But if I hardcode inside the subquery refactoring or use package level variable in the same session the query returns in a second

```
create or replace view loan_vw as 
        select * from (with loan_info as (select loan_table.*,commission_table.* 
                                           from loan_table,
                                          commission_table where 
                                          contract_id=commission_id
                                          and contract_id='HA001234TY56'
                                          )
                        select /*complex transformations */ from loan_info
                        where type <> 'PRINCIPAL'
                        union all 
                        select /*complex transformations */ from loan_info
                        where type = 'PRINCIPAL')
```

Since I use Business object I cannot use package level variable

So my question is there a hint in Oracle to tell the optimizer to first check the contract_id in loan_vw in the subquery refactoring

As requested the analytical function used is the below

```
select value_date, item, credit_entry, item_paid
from (
  select value_date, item, credit_entry, debit_entry,
    greatest(0, least(credit_entry, nvl(sum(debit_entry) over (), 0)
      - nvl(sum(credit_entry) over (order by value_date
          rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0))) as item_paid
  from your_table
)
where item is not null;
```

After following the advice given by Boneist and MarcinJ I removed the Sub query refactoring (CTE) and wrote one long query like the below which improved the performance from 3 min to 0.156 seconds

```
  create or replace view loan_vw as
  select /*complex transformations */
                               from loan_table,
                              commission_table where 
                              contract_id=commission_id
               and loan_table.type <> 'PRINCIPAL'
  union all
  select /*complex transformations */
                               from loan_table,
                              commission_table where 
                              contract_id=commission_id
               and loan_table.type = 'PRINCIPAL'
```

Comment: i think you have index on contract_id column as a result it got faster optimization in times of hardcoded

Comment: yes index is there on contract_id

Comment: so in times of creating view it got hang as not indexing facility available to optimizer when you are quering from view so it got slow or hang based on data volume it shows behave

Comment: yes based on data volume it hangs but since i am passing contract_id i want it to first look in loan_info

Comment: try to use Materialized view that may help  to you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm

Comment: other than mviews any other optimizer hint is there to acheive the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191647/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-psaraj12).

Comment: You might need the `/*+ inline */` hint inside your loan info select in the with clause, but bear in mind that this is an undocumented hint, and I've experienced ORA-600 errors as a result of using it. I'm saying this because you could be losing the benefit of indexes in this query. Alternatively, it could be that you can't push the predicate into the subquery because you're using analytic functions in your complex transformations, and perhaps there's not much you can do with that. Can you expand your queries to give an idea of the kind of transformations your queries are doing?

Comment: @Boneist Yes I am using Analytic function in the complex transformations which is  sum () over

Comment: Please update your question to include the various types of analytic functions; it's possible that tweaking them could help you (e.g. adding contract_id into the partition by clause). And by types, I mean the different types of partition by and order by clauses, as well as the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are these transformations really that complex you have to use `UNION ALL`? It's really hard to optimize something you can't see, but have you maybe tried getting rid of the CTE and implementing your calculations inline?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW loan_vw AS
SELECT loan.contract_id
     , CASE commission.type -- or wherever this comes from
         WHEN 'PRINCIPAL'
         THEN SUM(whatever) OVER (PARTITION BY loan.contract_id, loan.type) -- total_whatever

         ELSE SUM(something_else) OVER (PARTITION BY loan.contract_id, loan.type) -- total_something_else
      END AS whatever_something
  FROM loan_table loan 
 INNER 
  JOIN commission_table commission
    ON loan.contract_id = commission.commission_id
```

Note that if your analytic functions don't have `PARTITION BY contract_id` you won't be able to use an index on that `contract_id` column at all.

[Take a look at this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c37edb69f29b5bbdf9607480b76b1f77) (you'll have to click on `...` on the last result table to expand the results). Here, the `loan` table has an indexed (PK) `contract_id` column, but also `some_other_id` that is also unique, but not indexed and the predicate on the outer query is still on `contract_id`. If you compare plans for `partition by contract` and `partition by other id`, you'll see that index is not used at all in the `partition by other id` plan: there's a `TABLE ACCESS` with `FULL` options on the loan table, as compared to `INDEX` - `UNIQUE SCAN` in `partition by contract`. That's obviously because the optimizer cannot resolve the relation between `contract_id` and `some_other_id` by its own, and so it'll need to run `SUM` or `AVG` over the entire window instead of limiting window row counts through index usage.

What you can also try - if you have a dimension table with those contracts - is to join it to your results and expose the `contract_id` from the dimension table instead of the most likely huge loan fact table. Sometimes this can lead to an improvement in cardinality estimates through the usage of a unique index on the dimension table.

Again, it's really hard to optimize a black box, without a query or even a plan, so we don't know what's going on. CTE or a subquery can get materialized unnecessarily for example.

Comment: writing the query as per your suggestion solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update to include an example of the column list.

Given your updated query, I would suggest changing your view (or possibly creating a second view for querying single contract_ids, if your original view could be used to query for multiple contract_ids - unless, of course, the results of the original view only make sense for individual contract_ids!) to something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW loan_vw AS 
WITH loan_info AS (SELECT l.*, c.* -- for future-proofing, you should list the column names explicitly; if this statement is rerun and there's a column with the same name in both tables, it'll fail.
                   FROM   loan_table l
                          INNER JOIN commission_table c ON l.contract_id = c.commission_id -- you should always alias the join condition columns for ease of maintenance.
                  )
SELECT value_date,
     item,
     credit_entry,
     debit_entry,
     GREATEST(0,
            LEAST(credit_entry,
                NVL(SUM(debit_entry) OVER (PARTITION BY contract_id), 0)
                  - NVL(SUM(credit_entry) OVER (PARTITION BY contract_id ORDER BY value_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0))) AS item_paid
FROM   loan_info
WHERE  TYPE <> 'PRINCIPAL'
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM   loan_info
WHERE  TYPE = 'PRINCIPAL';
```

Note that I've converted your join into ANSI syntax, because it's easier to understand than the old style joins (easier to separate join conditions from predicates, for a start!).

Comment: I have done the partition by contract_id performance improved from 3 min to 2 min but still it is to long

Comment: Apologies, I missed one of the `partition by contract_id` from my answer. I'm assuming you updated both `SUM(...)` analytic functions?

Comment: did you try the inline hint as I suggested in my first comment? My guess is that the loan_info subquery is being materialized before the predicate is applied, meaning you lose the benefit of any index on contract_id. If that works, I would suggest you rewrite the query to avoid the union all and/or the factored subquery (aka the "with" clause). See MarcinJ's answer for going with a single access to the tables.

Comment: reduced to 1 min from 2 min after using inline

Comment: Your best bet would be to rewrite the query with only a single access to the loan_info subquery (or directly to the underlying tables with no subquery at all, as per MarcinJ's answer).

Comment: i removed the subquery and wrote one long query and the result returned in 0.156 second.thanks Boneist